# Why does javax.ejb.AsyncResult.isDone always throws exception?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, asynchronous, future

I think I misunderstand java ee asynchronous method invocation. I'm following the idea from this official [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkkqg.html). For void methods it's fine, but I want my asyncronous method to return a value:

```
@Asynchronous
public Future<String> processPayment(Order order) {
    ...
    String status = ...;
    return new AsyncResult<String>(status);
}
```

I have many such long running tasks in background, so I collect `List<Future<String>>` and loop through them to check if the task is completed. I do this check by

```
for(Future<String> future: listOfFutures) {
    if(future.isDone())
       // do something
}
```

But the code fails with `IllegalStateException:"Object does not represent an acutal Future"` when the method `AsyncResult.isDone()` gets called.

Well, then I read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/AsyncResult.html) and it made me very confused: official tutorial says **"Use AsyncResult.isDone()"** to check the status of asynchronous method whereas oficial javadoc says **"Don't dare using AsyncResult.isDone()"**.

I know that I could use `FutureTask<T>` together with `Callable<T>`, but this is java se part.

Could you explain me if it is possible to use **java ee asynchronous method invocation**?

Thank you!

P.S. I'm using Glassfish 3.1.2 and EJB 3.1

Comment: you should post the client code and the exception trace.

Comment: The *implementation* might return `AsyncResult` but the *client* shall never see this instance as the EE container is responsible to return a different `Future` which encapsulates the transport and whose `isDone` method will return `true` once the result has been transferred from the implementation to the client.

Comment: how did you inject async bean and call the method?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770672/java-asynchronous-methods-not-running-async

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, your question is "is it possible to use java ee asynchronous method invocation?" 
The answer is **yes**. And the 2 little bits of code in your question are correct. To fully diagnose what has gone wrong in your case, however, we would probably need to see more of the code.

A possibility is that you are not using the annotation "correctly". A super short code example of how is used can be read here:
https://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/async-methods/README.html

The important information on that example is that your *Asynchronous* method has to be declared an *Singleton* or *Stateless* bean (let's call it *container bean*), and in a different bean (or Servlet, or POJO with access to the right JNDI context, like in the link above) that we can call the *client* you make a call to your *container bean*. So to be clear, your *for* loop is in the *client*. Then your `AsyncResult` will behave like you want it to.

If you read the javadoc you linked to carefully, it says:

> The value specified in the constructor will be retrieved by the container and made available to the client.

and

> none of its instance methods should be called by the application

This means is that the `AsyncResult` class is sort of a "dumb wrapper" to let you implement the interface easily, but is not supposed to be used "for real".

Please notice that using the `ExecutorService` is the way to perform asynchronous calls when you are *not* implementing a EJB, or are outside a EJB container. The fact that is working for you makes me thing that you have a direct reference to the *container* class, instead of via the `@EJB` annotation or by a JNDI lookup.

Comment: Yes, now I got it, thank you @wzurita. I think I can accept your answer.

Answer (score -1):

If use Spring Framework, Use

```
org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncResult
```

instead of

```
javax.ejb.AsyncResult
```

Answer (score -2):

@Holger pointed me to the right direction in some sense: my problem is the implementation of `Future`, `AsyncResult` in this case. It turned out to be rather interesting. I looked into the `AsyncResult` class code and that is what i saw:

```
public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)
{
  throw new IllegalStateException("Object does not represent an acutal Future");
}

public boolean isCancelled()
{
  throw new IllegalStateException("Object does not represent an acutal Future");
}

public boolean isDone()
{
  throw new IllegalStateException("Object does not represent an acutal Future");
}
```

So it explains why I got that exception all the time.

The workaround for me was to return `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService.submit(new MyCallable<MyClass>(myClassInstance))` as `java.util.concurrent.Future<MyClass>` implementation. After it worked as expected.

Comment: this dude is happily calling it http://paddyweblog.blogspot.com/2010/04/ejb-31-asynchronous-session-beans.html