# can't shutdown wildfly gracefully

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, server, java-ee-6, wildfly

Wildfly 9 doesn't shut down in eclipse when I right click -> stop, but it does when I click on stop in the console.

When trying to shutdown gracefully the output in the console is:

```
18:36:08,342 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 5) WFLYSRV0211: Suspending server
18:36:08,345 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Thread-2) WFLYSRV0220: Server shutdown has been requested.
18:36:08,428 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) WFLYUT0022: Unregistered web context: /csbasement
18:36:08,441 INFO  [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) RewriteFilter shutting down...
18:36:08,442 INFO  [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) RewriteFilter deactivated.
18:36:08,460 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0019: Host default-host stopping
```

The state of the server stays on stopping after that, not stopped.
And after 5 minutes or so, eclipse dialog failed to stop the server and this in console:

```
19:29:11,600 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffffc0a80104:6ad8fb66:5637aa44:c in state  RUN
19:29:11,601 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012095: Abort of action id 0:ffffc0a80104:6ad8fb66:5637aa44:c invoked while multiple threads active within it.
19:29:11,601 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012108: CheckedAction::check - atomic action 0:ffffc0a80104:6ad8fb66:5637aa44:c aborting with 1 threads active!
19:29:11,602 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012121: TransactionReaper::doCancellations worker Thread[Transaction Reaper Worker 0,5,main] successfully canceled TX 0:ffffc0a80104:6ad8fb66:5637aa44:c
```

After that the status is started even though I get 404 when trying to access a page of the webapp. I'm not sure what that means in the error: `Unregistered web context: /csbasement`. csbasement is the name of the webapp. Also when using clean the webapp state stays on starting so I've to stop the server, clean and start it again.

When starting I've this error but it starts normally :

```
19:17:16,344 ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (XNIO-1 I/O-2) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Edit:

```
@Eager
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class LaunchBackgroundTasks {

     @EJB
    private TwitterLatestTweetInterface twitterService;
    private LinkedBlockingQueue<Tweet> msgList;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        twitterService.makeLatestsTweets();
    }
}

@Stateless
public class TwitterLatestTweets {
    private LinkedBlockingQueue<Tweet> tweets;
    @Inject
    private LaunchBackgroundTasks caller;


    @Asynchronous
    public void makeLatestsTweets() {
          ...
        while (!hosebirdClient.isDone()) {
            try {
                String msg = msgQueue.take();
                Tweet tweet = format(msg);
                tweets.put(tweet);
                caller.setMsgList(tweets);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                hosebirdClient.stop();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

And I'd get the tweets on a jsf page like so :  `value="#{launchBackgroundTasks.msgList}"`, That was "working" on glassfish.

This doesn't start asynchronously ([java @Asynchronous Methods: not running async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770672/java-asynchronous-methods-not-running-async))

```
@Eager
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class TwitterLatestTweets {

    private LinkedBlockingQueue<Tweet> tweets;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        makeLatestsTweets();
    }

    //notation not taken into account
    @Asynchronous
    public void makeLatestsTweets() {


        // hosebirdClient is twitter streaming so I'm getting tweets as long as the app is alive.
        while (!hosebirdClient.isDone()) {
            try {
                String msg = msgQueue.take();
                Tweet tweet = format(msg);
                tweets.put(tweet);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                hosebirdClient.stop();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @BalusC Since I can't find the way to interrupt the thread of an `@Asynchronous` method, I used instead a normal thread. Is my answer viable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was stubborn to use `@Asynchronous` because I wanted my thread to be managed but I just can't get it working like that. I can't find the way to interrupt the thread of an async method. So I'm back to a normal thread which does the job I want.

```
@Eager
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class LaunchBackgroundTasks {

    @EJB
    TopStreamInterface topStream;
    Thread twitterThread;

List<Tweet> tweets;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        tweets = new LinkedList<Tweet>();
        twitterThread = new Thread(new TwitterLatestTweets(this));
        twitterThread.start();

    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroyTwitterClient() {
        twitterThread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

and the thread :

```
public class TwitterLatestTweets implements Runnable {

    private final static String BUNDLE_BASENAME = "configuration.twitter";
    private final static String CONSUMER_KEY = ResourceBundle.getBundle(
            BUNDLE_BASENAME).getString("consumerKey");
    private final static String CONSUMER_SECRET = ResourceBundle.getBundle(
            BUNDLE_BASENAME).getString("consumerSecret");
    private final static String TOKEN = ResourceBundle.getBundle(
            BUNDLE_BASENAME).getString("token");
    private final static String SECRET = ResourceBundle.getBundle(
            BUNDLE_BASENAME).getString("secret");
    // private LinkedBlockingQueue<Tweet> msgList;
    private List<Long> userIds;
    private int tweetListSize = 10;

    TwitterLatestTweets(LaunchBackgroundTasks caller) {
    this.caller = caller;
    }
        @Override
    public void run() {
        makeLatestsTweets();
    }

    public void makeLatestsTweets() {

        BlockingQueue<String> msgQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>(100);
        StatusesFilterEndpoint hosebirdEndpoint = new StatusesFilterEndpoint();

        userIds = addFollowings();

        hosebirdEndpoint.followings(userIds);

        Authentication hosebirdAuth = new OAuth1(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET,
                TOKEN, SECRET);

        Client client = new ClientBuilder().name("test")
                .hosts(Constants.STREAM_HOST).endpoint(hosebirdEndpoint)
                .authentication(hosebirdAuth)
                .processor(new StringDelimitedProcessor(msgQueue)).build();

        client.connect();

        while (!client.isDone()) {
            try {
                String msg = msgQueue.take();
                //...
                caller.setTweets(aTweetLinkedList);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("twitter interrupted");
                client.stop();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```